# ASP.NET MVC: How can I open simultaneously all documents (say pdf's) , with same particular ID with one controller action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, model-view-controller

I have an SQL table with more than one attachement (pdf's) with same IDsomething. 
I would like to open all pdf's at the same time in separate tabs/windows with one action on the IDsomething. (I allow popups in browser.)
My PDF's have different paths (in a shared folder on a network) inserted in the SQL table column but same IDsomething so they have different row id's in the table.

I can open the first pdf with FirstOrDefault but how could I open all the PDF's in different windows/tabs?

Answer (score 1):

Since single response can only contain either on page or one binary file you can't achieve your goal with single invocation of one controller action.

One possible implementation - return list of urls to individual files in first request and than open each in new window with JavaScript.

Comment: Beat me to it. I was in the middle of writing pretty much the exact same answer. Oh well.